# Val2 function in iWork Numbers?

Tags: iwork-numbers, iwork

Is there equivalent Excel Val2() function in Numbers? I want to get value of a cell, which contains formula. What I need to get the result text from the cell.

The following is example data:

```
A   B   C
?   0   what?
```

For example, in cell A1 I have a function like:

```
=Right(C1)
```

which is the end character of string in C1. Then I need to use the result of A1 in B1

```
=CountIf(C$1:C1, A1 = "?")
```

As you can see, the result is 0. I think that A1 in above expression is referring to the formula of A1, instead of its result. Is there anything available like this in Numbers?

```
=Count(C$1:C1, Val2(A1) = "?")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out in a way. My usage of CountIf is not correct. It should be:

```
 =CountIf(C$1:C1, "?")
```

Where the second the filter to be matched not condition with true of false result.

Still I don't know if there is Val2 Excel similar function in Numbers.